# Login Error In Android

Tags: android, if-statement

I am trying to display that username and password do not match  if I filling up the wrong username and password . On button click with the proper name and password it is working perfectly and display the message login successful but else condition is not working. Where am I wrong? Tell me how can I resolve this problem and display the message username or password not match.

**LogIn.java**

```
    private class SigIn extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
              private final Context _context;  

              public SigIn(Context context){
                    _context = context;

                }
            ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @SuppressLint("WorldReadableFiles")
            @Override
            protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
            {
                ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
                {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    try 
                    {
                        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait signing in...");
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                        {
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                pDialog.show();
                            }
                        });

                        JSONObject job= new JSONObject();
                        euid = uedit.getText().toString();
                        epass = pedit.getText().toString();

                        euid.replace("" ,"%20");
                        epass.replace("" ,"%20");
                        job.put("status_key","2");
                        job.put("method", "login");
                        job.put("email", euid);
                        job.put("password",epass );



                    /*
                        System.out.print("latitude is "+latitude);
                        job.put("latitude",latitude);
                        job.put("longitude",longitude);*/

                        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(job.toString());

                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/mobileapp_now/webservice.php");

                        httppost.setEntity(se);

                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                          String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                          System.out.println("response "+data);

                          JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);

                        Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));

                        JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("driver_details");  
                        Log.d("Array", jArray.toString(4));
                        JSONObject adv= jo.getJSONObject("advertisement_count");  
                        advertisement_count=adv.getString("count(*)");
                        System.out.print("advertisemnet"+advertisement_count);              
                        for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            try {
                            JSONObject jsob = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    mfname = jsob.getString("first_name");
                                    msname = jsob.getString("Surname");
                                    mun = jsob.getString("unit_no");
                                    mstreet = jsob.getString("street_name");
                                    msuburb = jsob.getString("Suburb");
                                    mstate = jsob.getString("State");
                                    mpassword = jsob.getString("password");
                                    mpostcode = jsob.getString("post_code");
                                    mlicense = jsob.getString("driving_lic");
                                    mid = jsob.getString("authority_id");
                                    mmobile = jsob.getString("mobile_no");
                                    memail = jsob.getString("Email");
                                    login_token=jsob.getString("login_token");
                                    mimagelicense=jsob.getString("license_pic");
                                    mauthcard=jsob.getString("audit_card_pic");
                                    mpic=jsob.getString("face_pic");
     } catch (JSONException e) {
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                            } 
    }
    pref=getSharedPreferences("Driver", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor edit=pref.edit();

                        edit.putString("mfname", mfname);
                        edit.putString("msname", msname);
                        edit.putString("mun", mun);
                        edit.putString("mstreet", mstreet);
                        edit.putString("msuburb", msuburb);
                        edit.putString("mpassword", mpassword);
                        edit.putString("mpostcode", mpostcode);
                        edit.putString("mlicense", mlicense);
                        edit.putString("mid", mid);
                        edit.putString("mmobile", mmobile);
                        edit.putString("memail", memail);
                        edit.putString("login_token", login_token);
                        edit.putString("mimagelicense", mimagelicense);
                        edit.putString("mauthcard", mauthcard);
                        edit.putString("mpic", mpic);
                        edit.putString("advertisement_count", advertisement_count);
                        edit.commit();

        if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
                            {
                                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                                alert.setTitle("Login !!!");
                                //alert.setTitle("Login unsuccessfull !");
                            alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                                //alert.setMessage("Username and password does not match.");
                                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int whichButton) 
                                    {
                                        pDialog.dismiss();
                                        dialog.dismiss();

                                        /*Intent tabint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),agreement.class);
                                               startActivity(tabint);*/
                                        Intent tabint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),agreement.class);
                                           startActivity(tabint);
                                }
                                });
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        alert.show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            else if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("300"))
                            {
                                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                                alert.setTitle("Login!!!");
                                alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int whichButton) 
                                    {
                                        pDialog.dismiss();
                                        dialog.dismiss();

                                        //Intent tabint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),agreement.class);
                                             //  startActivity(tabint);
                                }
                                });
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        alert.show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                                alert.setTitle("Alert !");
                                alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",

                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int whichButton) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();

                                    }
                                });
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                                {
                                    public void run() 
                                    {
                                        pDialog.dismiss();

                                        alert.show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }


                        }
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    return params;
                }
```

After login with different username and password it will give me error in log cat like:

```
    -10 03:41:20.550: W/System.err(32253): org.json.JSONException: No value for driver_details
    06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
    06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:549)
    06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$SigIn.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:263)
    06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$SigIn.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
    06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    06-10 03:41:20.560: W/System.err(32253):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    06-10 03:41:20.570: W/System.err(32253):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    06-10 03:41:20.570: W/System.err(32253):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
```

Comment: `org.json.JSONException: No value for driver_details`,

Comment: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray(java.lang.String)

Comment: how can I resolve this.

Comment: you have tried to get value from your json with `driver_details` key that doesn't exists on your json, debug your app, and see what is the right key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the code where you get data from json and store it in shared prefrence inside if conditon like this..

```
                    //preciding codes here...

              JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);

              Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));

              if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
              {
                    JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("driver_details");  
                    Log.d("Array", jArray.toString(4));
                    JSONObject adv= jo.getJSONObject("advertisement_count");  
                    advertisement_count=adv.getString("count(*)");
                    System.out.print("advertisemnet"+advertisement_count);              
                    for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        try {
                                JSONObject jsob = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                mfname = jsob.getString("first_name");
                                msname = jsob.getString("Surname");
                                mun = jsob.getString("unit_no");
                                mstreet = jsob.getString("street_name");
                                msuburb = jsob.getString("Suburb");
                                mstate = jsob.getString("State");
                                mpassword = jsob.getString("password");
                                mpostcode = jsob.getString("post_code");
                                mlicense = jsob.getString("driving_lic");
                                mid = jsob.getString("authority_id");
                                mmobile = jsob.getString("mobile_no");
                                memail = jsob.getString("Email");
                                login_token=jsob.getString("login_token");
                                mimagelicense=jsob.getString("license_pic");
                                mauthcard=jsob.getString("audit_card_pic");
                                mpic=jsob.getString("face_pic");
                         } catch (JSONException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                        } 
                    }

                    pref=getSharedPreferences("Driver", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit=pref.edit();

                    edit.putString("mfname", mfname);
                    edit.putString("msname", msname);
                    edit.putString("mun", mun);
                    edit.putString("mstreet", mstreet);
                    edit.putString("msuburb", msuburb);
                    edit.putString("mpassword", mpassword);
                    edit.putString("mpostcode", mpostcode);
                    edit.putString("mlicense", mlicense);
                    edit.putString("mid", mid);
                    edit.putString("mmobile", mmobile);
                    edit.putString("memail", memail);
                    edit.putString("login_token", login_token);
                    edit.putString("mimagelicense", mimagelicense);
                    edit.putString("mauthcard", mauthcard);
                    edit.putString("mpic", mpic);
                    edit.putString("advertisement_count", advertisement_count);
                    edit.commit();

                    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            alert.setTitle("Login !!!");
                            //alert.setTitle("Login unsuccessfull !");
                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                            //alert.setMessage("Username and password does not match.");
                            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) 
                                {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                    /*Intent tabint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),agreement.class);
                                           startActivity(tabint);*/
                                    Intent tabint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),agreement.class);
                                       startActivity(tabint);
                            }
                            });
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    alert.show();
                                }
                            });
                    }



                    else if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("300"))
                    { 
                        //reamining codes...
```

Comment: I have created two services

Comment: show us what response you are getting when you type wrong credentials.

Comment: isnt this your api url: http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/mobileapp_now/webservice.php ??

Comment: services when username or password is wrong : response {"message":"Username and Password does not match. Kindly try again.","err-code":"300","err":""}
  D/response(547):

 {    
"err": "",
 
  
          "message": "Username and Password does not match. Kindly try  again.",
  
  "err-code": "300"

}

Comment: you are trying to get "driver-detail". but when you have wrong details, clearly this thing is not in the response. thats why you are getting this error.  Let me edit my answer and may be that'll help you

Comment: yes sure you can :) and dont forget to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: hello sir. i want to drop my existing drivers table in sqlite.i try every thing but its remain in sqliite...plz see the link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162044/delete-sqlite-database-in-android